# Security concerns with an HTTPS iframe in an HTTPS page

Tags: html, security, iframe, https

Are there any security concerns when putting an HTTPS iframe in an HTTPS page?  Or security wise is it essentially the same as having a single HTTPS page.

(The iframe content is coming from a different domain if that makes a difference)

Comment: A different *server* or a different *domain*?

Comment: @T.Rob, different domain.  Thanks for asking
For example:  

https://www.example123.com/donate

would have an iframe in it for

https://www.someothersite.com/donatecollection.asp

Comment: Don't just retag a question. you should also edit it's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no on-the-wire privacy implications associated with this compared with a normal HTTPS page, but bear in mind that you're doubling the number of servers and probably companies involved.

Browser exploits, popups and adware can all be served under HTTPS - and visiting a HTTPS site that isn't in your control can expose your users to privacy violations if the HTTPS URL reveals personal information about one of your users - for example if you serve https://www.example.com/redir.php?url= + CURRENT_URL and you've logged in a user using a GET postback with the username and password in the URL, you could be exposing this to third party sites.

Other than that, there are no issues associated with embedding third-party HTTPS sites into your own HTTPS pages.

Comment: *Other than that, there are no issues associated with embedding third-party HTTPS sites into your own HTTPS pages.* Not even intellectual property rights issues or same-origin policy?

Comment: Intellectual property rights have nothing to do with computer security. The same-origin policy is embedded into your browser, and doesn't require you to do anything special - if the inner iframe wants to do bad things to your host page, it simply can't - and vice-versa. This is obviously the case otherwise lots of websites on the internet would load up your bank details in a hidden iframe and script it to withdraw all of your money.

Comment: So if the statement read "Other than that, there are no **security** issues associated.." it would be correct?  Regarding SOP, I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. If the embedded page has scripting referring to the absolute rather than relative containers and "top" isn't what it expects, then its functionality breaks due to a security constraint. Maybe that's a content issue to you. OK, no problem.